# Is a change made to contextvars in a process pool not propagated to the main process running the asyncio loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-3.7

Below is the code snippet that I ran:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import asyncio
import contextvars


ctx = contextvars.ContextVar('ctx', default=None)
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

def task():
    print(f'inside pool process, ctx: {ctx.get()}')
    ctx.set('co co')
    return ctx.get()

async def execute():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ctx.set('yo yo')
    ctx_from_pool = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, task)
    ctx_from_async = ctx.get()
    print(f'ctx_from_async: {ctx_from_async}')
    print(f'ctx_from_pool: {ctx_from_pool}')
    ctx.set('bo bo')

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(execute()))
    ctx_from_main = ctx.get()
    print(f'ctx_from_main: {ctx_from_main}')

main()
```

Output:

```
inside pool process, ctx: yo yo
ctx_from_async: yo yo
ctx_from_pool: co co
ctx_from_main: None
```

My understanding is that the reason for contextvars change `ctx.set('co co')` made by process pool to not propagated to the main process is that when assigning the task, a copy of the variables are made using pickle due to which the change was made on a different copy of the variable rather than the one which is accessed by the main process. However, I am not completely sure of this as I don't have a lot of experience with ProcessPoolExecutor.
Could someone throw some additional light on the same? Also, what can be done to have a seamless manipulation of the contextvars across asyncio loop and process pool executor?

Comment: If your goal is to share stuff between the main process and its pool workers, contextvars are the wrong tool for the job. Instead, use the objects [designed for sharing state](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) between processes.

Comment: the use case here is implicit sharing of request headers related to user context and unique request id. once the aiohttp server receives them from the incoming request, it needs to populate the same on all the outgoing requests that it will make to other services. even though right now, the process pool would only be required to read the ctx and not manipulate (manipulation will only be done by the aiohttp middleware which will run in the main process as of now), but this was just a test if in case we need to do that in future and how we can handle that situation

Comment: If by "sharing" you mean sending it off to the subprocess without either needing to see subsequent modifications to the objects, what you have does just that, and your understanding is correct. In your place I would prefer not to send `contextvars.ContextVar` to a subprocess, for two reasons: 1) it is not obvious that it will always be serializable, and 2) it might give off the impression to a human reader that you're creating a mutable object shared with the subprocess, which is in fact not the case.

Comment: Note that it only works with `fork`. In `spawn` the `ContextVar.get()` will return `None` in the subprocess.